# Actions() in LibGDX accumulate error whith every click on a sprite

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Actions accumulate an error that increases with each click.

I am making a game. When I click on the sprite a dialog box comes out. This dialog box comes out with the animation that I do through Actions(). Initially, the dialog box smoothly opens and scales and also smoothly closes. But after about 10 openings and closures of the dialog box, an error becomes noticeable. The dialog box begins to jerk open and close. The more I click on the sprite, the more torn the animation of dialog box turns out.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    vector2 = new Vector2(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY);

if (sprite_1.getBoundingRectangle().contains(vector2)) {
    switch (serverClass.point1) {
        case 0:
            Gdx.app.log("1", "drops");

win_dialog_alpha_white.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(.2f)); //this window covers all sprites
stage_dialogs.addActor(win_dialog_01_1);

win_dialog_01_1.setModal(true);

win_dialog_01_1.addAction(
    Actions.fadeOut(0));

win_dialog_01_1.addAction(Actions.parallel(
    Actions.fadeIn(.2f)
    , Actions.scaleTo(1.05f, 1.05f, .2f)));

win_dialog_01_1.addAction(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.delay(.2f)
    , Actions.scaleTo(1, 1, .2f)));

button_close.addListener(new ClickListener() {
@Override
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
    win_dialog_alpha_white.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(.3f));
    win_dialog_01_1.setModal(false);
    win_dialog_01_1.addAction(Actions.parallel(
        Actions.fadeOut(.4f)
            , Actions.scaleTo(1.05f, 1.05f, .2f)));
    win_dialog_01_1.addAction(Actions.sequence(
        Actions.delay(.2f)
            , Actions.scaleTo(1, 1, .2f)));
                    }
    });
    break;
```

The "win_dialog_01_1" is a separate class (extends Window), but the button  "button_close" created in a main class and then added to the instance of "win_dialog_01_1".

I can not finde where the error is accumulate.

Comment: Is adding the listener to `button_close` something you do every time it is touched? I can't tell because you've removed so much code I can't see the context. If you are adding copies of the same listeners each time you use the dialog, it will have many copies of the same actions working simultaneously, which would cause the jerkiness you described.

Comment: I edited the code. The button_close is added in the show() method. The class is very big, I can't write it here.

Comment: I still can't tell. Are you calling `button_close.addListener` inside the `touchDown` method?

Comment: Yes,  the button_close.addListener inside the touchDown method. Can’t I do that?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I took button_close.addListener out of the touchDown method and it looks like the problem is gone. Thanks for the help.